# Four Lemma with E-exact Sequences

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

- An *e-exact sequence* is a sequence of $R$-modules and $R$-module homomorphisms
  \begin{align*}
  \cdots \rightarrow M_{i-1} \xrightarrow{f_{i-1}} M_i \xrightarrow{f_i} M_{i+1} \rightarrow \cdots 
  \end{align*}
  that is e-exact at each $M_i$. That is, $\text{Im}(f_{i-1}) \leq_e \ker(f_i)$ for all $i$. This means that $\text{Im}(f_{i-1})$ is a submodule of $\ker(f_i)$ such that $\text{Im}(f_{i-1}) \cap N \neq 0$ for all nonzero submodules $N$ of $\ker(f_i)$. Equivalently, $\text{Im}(f_{i-1}) \cap Rx \neq 0$ for all $x \in \ker(f_i)$ such that $x \neq 0$.
- An $R$-module homomorphism is called a *monomorphism* (or *monic*, for short) if it is injective. An $R$-module homomorphism is called an *epimorphism* (or *epic*, for short) if it is surjective.
- An $R$-module homomorphism $g:A \rightarrow B$ is *e-epic* if $\text{Im}(g) \leq_e B$. This means that $\text{Im}(g)$ is a submodule of $B$ such that $\text{Im}(g) \cap B' \neq 0$ for all nonzero submodules $B'$ of $B$. Equivalently, $\text{Im}(g) \cap Rb \neq 0$ for all $b \in B$ such that $b \neq 0$.

With the above established, I have just two (very similar) questions regarding the proof of Lemma 2.2 (which introduces a generalization of the four lemma to e-exact sequences) in [this paper](https://www.koreascience.or.kr/article/JAKO202013461499258.pdf):

For the proof of (1), it's stated that "Since $\text{Im}(t_3) \leq_e B_3$, $\text{Im}(t_3) \cap Rg_2(b_2) \neq 0$". But, why is $g_2(b_2) \neq 0$? Since $b_2$ is an arbitrary non-zero element of $B_2$, this would suggest that the kernel of $g_2$ is trivial, but I do not see why this is true from the given assumptions. Similarly, why is $rsb_2 - t_2(a_2) \neq 0$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regarding the first question:** If $0\neq b_2\in B_2$ is such that $g_2(b_2)=0$, we will show that $Im(t_2)\cap Rb_2\neq 0$.

So assume $g_2(b_2)=0$, then $Im (g_1)\cap Rb_2\neq 0$, as the bottom row is e-exact at $B_2$. Let for some $r\in R$, $rb_2=g_1(b_1)$.

If $b_1=0$ then $rb_2=0$, hence $b_2=0$ as $B$ is torsion free $R$-module.

If $b_1\neq0$, then $t_1$ being $e$-epic, implies $Im (t_1)\cap Rb_1\neq 0$. Let for some $s\in R$, $sb_1=t_1(a_1)$. Now $t_2f_1(a_1)=g_1t_1(a_1)=rsb_2$.

Hence, $Im(t_2)\cap Rb_2\neq 0$  (as $0\neq rsb_2\in Im(t_2)\cap Rb_2$).

**Regarding the 2nd question:** If $rsb_2-t_2(a_2)=0,$ i.e. $rsb_2=t_2(a_2)$, then again $Im(t_2)\cap Rb_2\neq 0$ since  $0\neq rsb_2\in Im(t_2)\cap Rb_2$.

Comment: In both cases, it looks like you're trying to reach a contradiction by showing that $t_2$ is e-epic. I'm not sure where the contradiction comes in then, though.

Comment: Yes. The end goal of the proof there is to show that for any $0\neq b_2\in B_2$, $Im(t_2)\cap Rb_2\neq 0$. Now we are making cases: either $g_2(b_2)=0$ or $g_2(b_2)\neq 0$. In the first case follow the argument I gave. In the second case follow the argument in the paper.

Comment: Aah, I see. Thank you!